# Apostol Calculus - How do we go from 1.5 to 1.6 in introduction?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

The following is from Apostols *Calculus Volume 1* on page 6:

> For our purposes, we do not need the exact expressions given in the right-hand members of $(1.3)$ and $(1.4)$. All we need are the two *inequalities*
>   $$
>  1^2 + 2^2 + \dotsb + (n-1)^2
> < \frac{n^3}{3}
> < 1^2 + 2^2 + \dotsb + n^2
> \tag{I.5}
> $$
>   which are valid for every integer $n \geq 1$. These inequalities can be deduced easily as **consequences** of $(1.3)$ and $(\mathrm{I}.4)$, or they **can** be proved directly by induction. (A proof by induction is given in Section 14.1.)
>   If we multiply both inequalities in $(1.5)$ by $b^3/n^3$ and make use of $(1.1)$ and $(\mathrm{I}.2)$, we obtain
>   $$
>  s_n < \frac{b^3}{3} < S_n
>  \tag{I.6}
> $$
>   for every $n$. The inequalities in $(1.6)$ **tell** us that $b^3/3$ is a number which lies between $s_n$ […]

I do not understand why $(1.5)$ was valid for every interger $n \geq 1$ and then we obtain $(1.6)$ which is valid for every $n$.

Why is it valid for every $n$ and not for every $n \geq 1$?

Comment: When he says "for every n", he is assuming that n is a positive integer.

Comment: @user84413 ok so this is just a way of not repeating himself

Comment: Yes, that's right -- it's a common omission.